# How to integrate Google+ in to android application same as facebook?

Tags: android, google-plus

Hey I know this may be the duplicate post from other google plus post. But I still found nothing useful using that I can started my development. I want to integrate Google+ with my android application same as Facebook integration.

I want to show the latest posts as well as I want to post my application data from my application.

Can anyone help me to achieve this goal...??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Something for you interested..

[**Google+ Platform Java API Starter Project**](http://code.google.com/p/google-plus-java-starter/)

These starter projects demonstrate use of the `Google+` APIs and development best practices. You can use them as a starting point for building your own `Google+` applications.

These starter projects are the easiest way to get up and running with each library. They include everything needed to **use OAuth authentication** and demonstrate a few **simple API calls**. Even though some languages may not have starter projects, you can still use those libraries with `Google+`. Check the project home page for the library for instructions on how to get started.

They are available for these platforms:

```
* Command line
* Google AppEngine
* J2EE web application
* Android
```

Also play with [LiveDemo](https://plusjavastarterdemo.appspot.com/)

---

**UPDATE:**

Yes, you can integrate `LinkedIn` to your android application.

[**LinkedIn**](http://code.google.com/p/linkedin-j/)

`LinkedIn` provides a [REST based API](http://developer.linkedin.com/community/apis).
you can code to that API using the [Apache HTTP Client](http://d.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/HttpClient.html)

visit the `LinkedIn` Developers site [here](http://developer.linkedin.com)

also this might be helpful (I am not familiar with it, though):
http://code.google.com/p/jlinkedin-linkedin-java-api/

Also Here is the [sample project](http://esilo.pl/LITest.zip) and [Source-Code](http://code.google.com/p/linkedin-j/source/browse/#svn/trunk/linkedin-j-android/src/com/google/linkedinapi/android)

Also look at this SO Question [Posting LinkedIn message from Android application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5804257/posting-linkedin-message-from-android-application) and [LinkedIn integration with Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8237322/linkedin-integration-with-android)..

Thanks...

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I saw this sample its really nice. But I want to integrate Google+ same as we integrate Facebook in our android app. Have you any idea like that. In this tutorial user can only see the post but user cannt post the any data from android app. :(

Comment: Google+, still now not provide any sdk feature to use with Android like Facebook, The API is for core Google+ application development.. So If you want to make it you have to make application as per your need..

Comment: Ok.. I see.. Thanks for advice and proper answer in right way.. Can you tell me that can we integrate LinkedIn in our app?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Let me try. I am just informing that your sample project link is not working into your post( If anyone want then he/she will not able to find example that is why I am telling you this). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Google+ APIs https://developers.google.com/+/overview
Posting to activity stream might not be allowed.